# Doctrine command: how to display file and line where error occured

Tags: symfony, doctrine, mappedby

I'm new to Symfony and I'm developing an application.
I've created the YAML files to generate the PHP entities. When I run this command:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

I get this exception:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]     Notice:
>   Undefined index: mappedBy

With no more explanation. No file and line that point to the error.

Is there any way to make Symfony give more information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type in `app/console -h` to get full list of available options. You can pass `-v` option to display more information:

```
-v  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
```